# Show Bootstrap popover only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jsFiddlePlayer/vhg7csb7/3/

When you load the page and click on the "Blog" tab, it should show the popover for 5.6 seconds and then disappear. If the user clicks on another tab and returns to "Blog", it should not show the popover again. It should be only once per user visit to the page.

Currently, it shows the popover every time you visit the "Blog" tab. I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182629/configuring-a-bootstrap-popover-to-appear-only-once) ([Configuring a bootstrap popover to appear only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182629/configuring-a-bootstrap-popover-to-appear-only-once)), but the `destroy` method doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="r1 row" id="anch-story">
    <div class="c1 col-md-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a class="btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" href="#story-tab-1">Vision</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" href="#story-tab-2">Manufacturing</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" href="#story-tab-3">Press</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn-lg" data-toggle="tab" href="#story-tab-4">Blog</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="story-tab-1">
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="story-tab-2">
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="story-tab-3">
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="story-tab-4">
                <div id="page-selection" class="text-center">
                    <ul class="pagination bootpag pagination-lg">
                        <li data-lp="1" class="prev disabled"> <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                &#xf0d9;
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-lp="1" class="active"> <a href="javascript:void(0);">1</a>

                        </li>
                        <li data-lp="2"> <a href="javascript:void(0);">2</a>

                        </li>
                        <li data-lp="2" class="next"> <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                &#xf0da;
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#page-selection > ul').attr('title', 'Blog Post Navigation')
        .attr('data-content', 'Use these controls to easily and quickly navigate the blog posts.')
        .attr('data-placement', 'bottom')
        .attr('data-toggle','popover');  

    $('a[href="#story-tab-4"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $('#page-selection > ul').popover('show');  

        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('#page-selection > ul').popover('destroy');
            }, 5600);
    });

    $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        $('[data-toggle=popover]').each(function () {
            // hide any open popovers when the anywhere else in the body is clicked
            if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('destroy');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.next > a {
    font-family:'Fontawesome';
    content:"\f0d9";
}
.prev > a {
    font-family:'Fontawesome';
    content:"\f0da";
}
.prev > a, .next > a {
    font-size: 2.3em !important;
    max-height: 47px !important;
    padding-top: 2px !important;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can add some simple logic to check if the popover has been shown or not.

Something like this:

```
$('a[href="#story-tab-4"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {

    if($(this).data('popover-shown')) return;

    $(this).data('popover-shown', true);

    $('#page-selection > ul').popover('show'); 

    ...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/vhg7csb7/5/

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to implement your desired functionality. Add a variable to check if it has been shown already:

```
var shownYet=false;

if (!shownYet){
    shownYet=true;         
    $('#page-selection > ul').popover('show');  
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $('#page-selection > ul').popover('destroy');
    }, 5600);       
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhg7csb7/7/)